# My question is about why rbind function of R does not work for Gujarati text input

Tags: user-input

> library(tibble)
>   library(tidyr)
>   pos_tweets = rbind(c(‘મને આ કાર ગમે છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "pos_tweets = rbind(c(‘"
>                      c(‘આ દૃશ્ય સુંદર છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(‘"
>                      c(‘આ સવારે મને મજા આવે છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(‘"
>                      c(‘સંગીત રોમાંચક છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(‘"
>                      c(‘રમેશ મારો પાકો દોસ્ત છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(‘"
>                      c(કમળા ખૂબ રૂપાળી છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(\"
>                      c(અમારું બિલાડું રમતિયાળ છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(\"
>                      c(લાડુ તો ભાવે જ ને’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(\"
>                      c(વાડી લીલી છે’, ‘positive’),
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(\"
>                      c(ચોપડી રસપ્રદ છે’, ‘positive’)
>   Error: unexpected input in "                   c(\"
>   )
>   Error: unexpected ')' in ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either single quote marks '  or double quote marks  " must be used around the text.

Above are "strange" left quote and right quote, and fails the syntax check for allowed characters, and the text is not being recognized as a valid character string.  It is the result of SMART QUOTES, given by WORD resulting in characters  x93 and x94,  instead of x22.  See article I found 11/18/2018 at
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f

Change all left-quote to single or double, and then change all right-quote to the same.

Has nothing to do with text being Gujarati text.

c(‘મને આ કાર ગમે છે’, ‘positive’)     fails

Copy the above and paste into Notepad, and then change font size to 18 to see the difference.

both of these work

```
> pos_tweets = rbind(c("મને આ કાર ગમે છે", "positive"))
> pos_tweets = rbind(c('મને આ કાર ગમે છે', 'positive'))
```

Comment: My problem is solved following donPablo's suggestion. Thanks a lot!